# How can I delete n% of a list in regular indervalls while keeping its trends?

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

So, if I want to draw a graph on a 500pixel canvas, I can't do much with 200.000 coordinates to draw lines. How can I delete 99% of this list, while still roughly keeping the trend of the data?

My Idea was:

```
for(int i = 0; i<200000; i++)
{
    if(i%2000 == 0)
    {
        newList.Add(List[i])
    }
}
```

I am just not sure, if this is the most efficient way to do this. I know that certain trends might get lost in this, but It should still be good enough (unless there is a more efficient, faster algorithm)

There is the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), which is overkill I think, and also not really needed or even too inefficient for what I need.

Comment: Why do you think it would be overkill? It seems perfect for this purpose, especially in the general case where the precise fit function is unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than enumerating over each and only taking the 2000th element May I suggest skipping over all these values and only taking the nth element? That way it should complete the for loop much faster.

Another option is to average the 2000 points and add that as a single point.

I've included both approaches below:

```
var data = new List<float>(200000); 
var segmentLength = 2000;   
var newList = new List<float>();    

// Sampling, this is your idea, without enumerating over every single element
for (var i=0; i<data.Count(); i+=segmentLength)
{
    newList.Add(data[i]);
}

// Averaging
for (var i=0; i<data.Count(); i+=segmentLength)
{
    newList.Add(data.GetRange(i*segmentLength, segmentLength).Average())
}
```